# Using prototype citation grouping feature of MediaWiki Extension:Cite

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I use MediaWiki 1.35.1.

MediaWiki `Cite` extension has a prototype [reference collecting feature](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Cite#Citing_different_parts_of_the_same_source). I'd like to use it in my wiki. According to the note below, this one is only available in the [Beta-Cluster](https://en.wikipedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/Draft:Cut_the_Crap#cite_ref-3%7C) and indeed, I can use it on its sample pages. The Beta-Cluster [Special:Version](https://en.wikipedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/Special:Version) points to [69a5435](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/extensions/Cite/+/69a54351da8c9218fc74f715f58d15675eb1a083) revision of the extension being used. However, if I download this snapshot and place it in my extension folder, this feature still doesn't work and `extends` attribute is still not recognized. The error I've got is

```
Cite error: Invalid <ref> tag; invalid names, e.g. too many
```

How can I enable this feature in my own wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I need to set in `LocalSettings.php` following option:

```
$wgCiteBookReferencing = true;
```

I missed this because this is not mentioned anywhere in [Help:Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Cite) page. I've found it later in [Extension:Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite#Configuration) page.